# tkinter wrap text if larger than column width

Tags: python, tkinter, window-resize, ttk

I have 3 columns of dynamic content that. I want to each column to take up 1/3 of the windows width and to be resizeable. That's not a problem:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()


root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

ttk.Label(root, text='Hello World', width=1).grid(column=0, row=0, padx=2, sticky=(N,W,E))
ttk.Label(root, text='Some txt', width=1).grid(column=1, row=0, padx=2, sticky=(N,W,E))
ttk.Label(root, text='Yet some more text', width=1).grid(column=2, row=0, padx=2, sticky=(N,W,E))

root.geometry('400x600')
root.minsize(220,300)
root.mainloop()
```

The problem is that the content is dynamic and can therfore be any width - when the window is shrunk to minsize column 3 doesn't fit anymore. I want to wrap the text but need to do so in such a way that when the window is resized the text will be wraped/unwraped as needed. My main problem when I tried this was that **wraptext** is in text units and **width** is in pixels this means that I cannot write my own update function and call it every time the window is resized.

Edit: I am not concerned what the vertical height of the window is when I wrap the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Width for text in a label is in text units. (found http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm) so what you can do is

```
def display():
    window_width = root.winfo_width() #get current screen width
    wrapLen = screen_width/3
    tkk.Label(root, text="Some Text", width= ? ,wraplength=wrapLen).grid(column = 0, row=0)
```

The width can be decided using if statements depending on the screen_width for example it would look like

```
if window_width == 100:
    width = 4.5
elif window_width == 300:
    width = 13.5
```

These are close to the correct values.
I calculated with a width of 400 you can get a label width=55 meaning it should be

```
if screen_width == 400:
    width = 18
```

do these calculations yourself if you please.

**SIDE NOTE**

also as a side note your doing

```
from tkinter import *
```

which imports everything from tkinter. Then importing

```
from tkinter import ttk
```

which just reimports the ttk bit.

If I was you I would just do

```
import tkinter as tk
```

then everything just becomes

```
root = tk.Tk()
tk.Label()
tk.Button()
```

and so on.

Comment: can I ask where you got your conversion from text units to pixels from - your dividing by 22and2/9. What if i'm using a different font how can I calculate this conversion. Also root.winfo_screenwidth() gives the screen width - root.winfo_width() gives the window width. which is what you want if the widget is going to be resized. Lastly yes you can import tkinter once rather than twice but it's convention to import ttk separately which is why I do it.

Comment: @user1205406 I did it via implementation. 

I set the geometry to be 400x600 and then placed a label at 0,0
Through trial and error by having a long string as the labels text and then changing the width until the label just filled the window. 

If you want to check it with a different font then just change the font and go through that process but it should not be a problem once you have chosen a font. 

Also, If that is convention then cool and sorry for bringing it up, I have not seen (or at least noted) that convention before.

Comment: thanks - its a shame that there isn't a proper way of calculating this however I can manage by working it out for individual fonts.